# How to create Dropbox new account using Android Dropbox SDK in Android application?

Tags: android

I need creating new dropbox account using Android Dropbox SDK, but not any help or guideline regarding this functionality. I need create dropbox new account in my android application and then after login using this account. So anyone who has developing this type functionality please help me.